# Number partitioning: how to allow both 'light' and 'heavy' output?

Tags: python, design-patterns, library

I am working on a library for algorithms for [multiway number partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_number_partitioning).
One challenge I face is that some users need the entire partition, while other users need only the sums of the parts. For example, suppose the input is the following list: `[1,2,3,3,5,9,9]`, and the goal is to partition them into two subsets. Then the entire partition could be `[[9, 5, 2], [9, 3, 3, 1]]`, but if a user only needs the sums, then the output would be `[16, 16]`. In this case, it is a waste of time to maintain the lists.
Initially, I thought of writing two variants for each algorithm. For example, for the greedy number partitioning algorithm, I had:

```
def greedy_partition(numbins: int, items: List[float]):
    """
    Partition the given items using the greedy number partitioning algorithm.
    It return the entire partition, so it runs slower.

    >>> greedy_partition(numbins=2, items=[1,2,3,3,5,9,9])
    [[9, 5, 2], [9, 3, 3, 1]]
    >>> greedy_partition(numbins=3, items=[1,2,3,3,5,9,9])
    [[9, 2], [9, 1], [5, 3, 3]]
    """
    bins = [[] for _ in range(numbins)]
    for item in sorted(items, reverse=True):
        index_of_least_full_bin = min(range(numbins), key=lambda i: sum(bins[i]))
        bins[index_of_least_full_bin].append(item)
    return bins


def greedy_sums(numbins: int, items: List[float]):
    """
    Partition the given items using the greedy number partitioning algorithm.
    It returns only the sums, so it runs much faster.

    >>> greedy_sums(numbins=2, items=[1,2,3,3,5,9,9])
    [16, 16]
    >>> greedy_sums(numbins=3, items=[1,2,3,3,5,9,9])
    [11, 10, 11]
    """
    sums = [0 for _ in range(numbins)]
    for item in sorted(items, reverse=True):
        index_of_least_full_bin = min(range(numbins), key=lambda i: sums[i])
        sums[index_of_least_full_bin] += item
    return sums
```

This works, but the algorithm is duplicated. If I add more algorithms, I will have to write each of them twice.

EDIT: Of course, I can use only `greedy_partition`, and then take the sum of each part. But this is extremely inefficient when the number of items is large. For example, I tested both functions on increasing number of items, and got the following results (in seconds):

```
3 bins, 1000 items: greedy_partition=0.022589921951293945. greedy_sums=0.0010304450988769531.
3 bins, 10000 items: greedy_partition=2.2264041900634766. greedy_sums=0.013550519943237305.
3 bins, 20000 items: greedy_partition=9.81221604347229. greedy_sums=0.020364999771118164.
3 bins, 40000 items: greedy_partition=36.83849239349365. greedy_sums=0.04088854789733887.
```

My current solution is as follows. I defined an abstract class to handle the bins during the run:

```
class Bins(ABC):
    def __init__(self, numbins: int):
        self.num = numbins

    @abstractmethod
    def add_item_to_bin(self, item: float, bin_index: int):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def result(self):
        return None
```

I defined two sub-classes: one keeps only the sums, and the other keeps the partition too:

```
class BinsKeepingSums(Bins):
    def __init__(self, numbins: int):
        super().__init__(numbins)
        self.sums = numbins*[0]

    def add_item_to_bin(self, item: float, bin_index: int):
        self.sums[bin_index] += item

    def result(self):
        return self.sums

class BinsKeepingContents(BinsKeepingSums):
    def __init__(self, numbins: int):
        super().__init__(numbins)
        self.bins = [[] for _ in range(numbins)]

    def add_item_to_bin(self, item: float, bin_index: int):
        super().add_item_to_bin(item, bin_index)
        self.bins[bin_index].append(item)

    def result(self):
        return self.bins
```

Now, I can write the algorithm only once, sending the desired Bins structure as parameter:

```
def greedy(bins: Bins, items: List[float]):
    """
    Partition the given items using the greedy number partitioning algorithm.
    Return the partition.

    >>> greedy(bins=BinsKeepingSums(2), items=[1,2,3,3,5,9,9])
    [16, 16]
    >>> greedy(bins=BinsKeepingContents(2), items=[1,2,3,3,5,9,9])
    [[9, 5, 2], [9, 3, 3, 1]]
    """
    for item in sorted(items, reverse=True):
        index_of_least_full_bin = min(range(bins.num), key=lambda i: bins.sums[i])
        bins.add_item_to_bin(item, index_of_least_full_bin)
    return bins.result()
```

Before I implement some more algorithms, I will be happy for feedback regarding this solution. Particularly, how to make it more simple, general, intuitive and efficient.

<sub>NOTE: I asked a different question on a similar topic here [Greedy number partitioning algorithm](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/273970/greedy-number-partitioning-algorithm)</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Summing the items seems like a special case of the partitioning problem.
So I would implement it as an operation on the return value of the partitioning:

```py
def greedy_sums(numbins: int, items: list[float]) -> list[float]:
    """..."""

    return [sum(items) for items in greedy_partition(numbins, items)]
```

**Benefits:**

- No duplicated code
- Code reuse
- No complex classes

Your worry about "needlessly" keeping the lists to me sounds like premature and possibly useless optimization.
I would worry about that if and only if you'll find *significant* performance drops in real-world application of the algorithms.

**Performance**
Your performance loss comes from a suboptimal implementation of your partitioning algorithm. You can improve it, by tracking the sums as keys:

```py
def greedy_bins_and_sums(numbins: int, items: list[float]):
    """..."""
    bins = [[] for _ in range(numbins)]
    sums = [0] * numbins
    for item in sorted(items, reverse=True):
        index_of_least_full_bin = min(range(numbins), key=sums.__getitem__)
        bins[index_of_least_full_bin].append(item)
        sums[index_of_least_full_bin] += item
    return bins, sums
```

You can verify that it produces the same results with:

```
@contextmanager
def perf_count():

    start = perf_counter()
    yield
    print('Time:', perf_counter() - start)


def main():

    for size in (1000, 10000, 40000):
        lst = [randint(0, size) for _ in range(size)]

        with perf_count():
            parts1 = greedy_partition(3, lst)

        with perf_count():
            parts2, sums = greedy_bins_and_sums(3, lst)
            
        print(parts1 == parts2)
```

```
Time: 0.006648327998846071
Time: 0.001240477999090217
True
Time: 0.5112279509994551
Time: 0.012690333998762071
True
Time: 8.914125162998971
Time: 0.058278149999750894
True
```

This way, you can provide the user directly with the partitions and their sums as the function now calculates both.

By using `sums.__getitem__` you can get another small performance boost, since you spare one extra call to the wrapping lambda.

**A custom data structure**
If you prefer to use a custom data structure, another alternative would be to subclass `list` into a container that keeps track of its sums:

```py
class Bin(list):
    """Represents a bin with tracked sum."""
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.sum = 0
    
    def append(self, item: float | int) -> None:
        """Adds an item and updates its sum."""
        super().append(item)
        self.sum += item


def greedy(numbins: int, items: list[float]) -> list[Bin]:
    """
    Partition the given items using the greedy number partitioning algorithm.

    >>> greedy_partition(numbins=2, items=[1,2,3,3,5,9,9])
    [[9, 5, 2], [9, 3, 3, 1]]
    >>> greedy_partition(numbins=3, items=[1,2,3,3,5,9,9])
    [[9, 2], [9, 1], [5, 3, 3]]
    """
    partitions = [Bin() for _ in range(numbins)]

    for item in sorted(items, reverse=True):
        min(partitions, key=lambda b: b.sum).append(item)

    return partitions
```

This has the benefit, that users can still use the items like lists, but can also access its property `sum` to get the respective bin's sum without cost.

Comment: There are very substantial performance differences when the number of items is large. See my current edit.  
Since I write a library (and not a particular application), I would like to make it efficient from the start.

Comment: I am amazed at the performance improvement. I did not know that handling lists in python was so fast.